# How to save a list as a .csv file with python and pandas?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have three lists:

```py
title = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
emails = ['1@1', '1@2', '1@3']
links = ['http1', 'http2', 'http3']
```

I need to insert each of these lists to a column in the CSV file. In the next iteration, I erase the data from the lists and they are filled with new data which also needs to go into these columns without overwriting the previous data.

Example of table:

| Titles | Emails | Links |
| --- | --- | --- |
| title1 | 1@1 | http1 |
| title2 | 1@2 | http2 |
| title3 | 1@3 | http3 |
| title4 | 1@4 | http4 |
| title5 | 1@5 | http5 |
| title6 | 1@6 | http6 |

I tried the following:

```py
df.to_csv('content.csv', index=False, columns=list['Titles', 'Emails', 'Links'])
df['Titles'] = titles
df['Emails'] = emails
df['Links'] = links
```

But it returns the error: 
`pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a `DataFrame` object first, then assign the data and finally save it as a csv file:

```py
import pandas as pd

titles = ["Mr", "Ms", "Mrs"]
emails = ["anton@domain.com", "lina@domain.com", "katharina@domain.com"]
links = ["https://www.cbc.ca", "https://www.srf.ch", "https://www.ard.de"]

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Titles", "Emails", "Links"])
df["Titles"] = titles
df["Emails"] = emails
df["Links"] = links

df.to_csv("content.csv", index=False)
```

---

You can also assign the data to the `DataFrame` object right away when creating it:

```py
import pandas as pd

titles = ["Mr", "Ms", "Mrs"]
emails = ["anton@domain.com", "lina@domain.com", "katharina@domain.com"]
links = ["https://www.cbc.ca", "https://www.srf.ch", "https://www.ard.de"]

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Titles": titles,
    "Emails": emails,
    "Links": links
})

df.to_csv("content.csv", index=False)
```

---

**And** if you need to append to the csv file use `mode="a"`:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Titles": ["Ms"],
    "Emails": ["courtney@domain.como"],
    "Links": ["https://www.orf.at"]
})

# appends the new data to the csv file
df.to_csv("content.csv", mode="a", index=False, header=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a dataframe and then assign to each column and then export to csv:

```
titles = ['title1', 'title2', 'title3']
emails = ['1@1','1@2','1@3']
links = ['http1', 'http2', 'http3']
#Create Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame()
#assign columns
df['Titles'] = titles
df['Emails'] = emails
df['Links'] = links
# export to csv
df.to_csv('content.csv', index=False, columns=['Titles', 'Emails', 'Links'])
```